# Maintaining a constant distance between two sprites

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, distance

Here's a distance formula I run through the update method to keep track of the distance between 2 sprites:

```
-(void)distance
{
    double dx = (_spriteA.position.x - _spriteB.position.x);  //(x2 - x1);
    double dy = (_spriteA.position.y - _spriteB.position.y);  //(y2 - y1);
    dist = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}

-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    [self distance]; //Calculate A & B distance
    if (dist > 50)
    {
        //What to write here to keep a constant distance between A & B?
        [_spriteB runAction:[SKAction moveTo:(_spriteA.position) duration:1]];
    }
}
```

Distance is tracked well but the if statement has problems. Specifically the actual action being run on sprite B. What ends up happening is sprite B moves toward sprite A in a yo-yo like fashion non-stop - even when sprite A isn't moving. I need sprite B to only move when sprite A is moved and retaining the distance of 50. Sprite A only moves when a person touches the screen. Please help.

Comment: SKConstraint class is available from iOS 8, and the distance:toNode: method creates a constraint that keeps a node within a certain distance of another node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SKConstraint` class to maintain the distance between the two nodes. 
For example :

```
let node1 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(20, 10))
node1.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)
self.addChild(node1)

let node2 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blueColor(), size: CGSizeMake(10, 20))
node2.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2 - 50)
self.addChild(node2)

// The upper and lower limit is set to 50 to maintain a constant distance.
let constraint = SKConstraint.distance(SKRange(lowerLimit: 50, upperLimit: 50), toNode : node1) 
node2.constraints = [constraint]

node1.runAction(SKAction.moveToY(100, duration: 2.0))
```

In Objective C

```
SKSpriteNode *node1 = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor redColor]
                                                    size:CGSizeMake(20, 10)];
node1.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
[self addChild:node1];

SKSpriteNode *node2 = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor redColor]
                                                     size:CGSizeMake(10, 20)];
node2.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2 - 50);
[self addChild:node2];

// The upper and lower limit is set to 50 to maintain a constant distance.
SKConstraint *constraint = [SKConstraint distance:[SKRange rangeWithLowerLimit:50 upperLimit:50] toNode:node1];
node2.constraints = @[constraint];

[node1 runAction:[SKAction moveToY:100 duration:2.0]];
```

Comment: But is there also an Objective-C example? I haven't gotten to Swift yet.

Comment: Before this thread dies out, I have one last question. So everything works perfectly now! But if I tap the screen too quickly, for some reason, more node2's are spawned. This is a weird bug. As I tap, node1 begins to move from right to left (until it reaches a certain location) because of [self.node1 runAction:[SKAction moveByX:(-10) y:(1) duration:1]]; I assume tapping the screen to quickly compounds the speed of node1 & causes node2 to not keep up? Could this be why more node2's are spawned?

Comment: i need to see your code to know what exactly the problem is. The speed shouldn't cause a new node to spawn.

Comment: Opa, I figured it out. Thanks for the help!